How Do I incorporate the basis spread between 2 currencies in a forward deal?
Lets assume I'm doing a yen/usd fx forward, the yen is my domestic currency. The basis spread between these currencies tells me the demand for 1 currency relative to the other.
The formula for an fx forward rate is -
spot * (1+rate(domestic))/(1+rate(foreign))
Where would i add the negative basis against the usd?
In the numerator or the denominator?
Would really appreciate the help.

By convention the currency basis of the yen vs the usd is applied to the rate of the yen (if negative it subtracts from it).

but doesnt this mean that effectively Im lowering the forward rate, thus making the yen "stronger" against the usd? isnt that counter intuitive? I would think that if the demand for the dollar would be higher than the yen i would need to compensate the usd lender more.

I agree you add it to the yen rate. There is a numerical example here for the same concept using EURUSD -> https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/f_fxf.html#introduction

Generally, FX forwards are market quoted, unless you are the market maker? E.g. if you have access to BBG, FRD will show you the quoted FX forwards. So usually there is no need to compute this manually.

@imao adding negative basis to the yen interest rate indeed makes the yen forward fx rate ‘stronger’, but this makes sense: the more negative the basis, the more spot dollars are in demand and therefore on a relative basis the weaker the forward dollar.  There are lots of ways of thinking about this .

I do understand that logic but then how does the USD lender get compensated in the transaction? If at the end of the day he needs to give more dollars for the same amount of yen?

It is not that the lender of usd gets compensated, it is the "borrower of USD by way of a currency swap with JPY" who pays a penalty, or is disadvantaged by the existence of the negative basis on these cross currency transactions.
